# How should I delete object in OpsCenter?

Tags: powershell, opscenter

How can I delete an object in NetBackup OpsCenter using view_exportimport.bat ?
I have XML like this:

```
<!-- validation of xml -->
<application version="2.0">
    <objects>
        <object id="o3" name="tsg003.machine.test" action="delete" type="CLIENT"/>
    </objects>
</application>
```

After this, through PowerShell I execute this script:

```
[PATH]\view_exportimport.bat -i -f "[PATH_TO_XML]\file.xml" --usr "username" --pass "password" --domain "MyDomain" --domaintype "type"
```

This finished execution and I have no results. This object remain in OpsCenter.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches I found that this is not possible. You just can try to interact directly with database file, which is not recommended.